# Why does the Keras API require the input shape in the first layer, since it actually works well without it?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using `tf.keras` from TensorFlow 1.9.0. It seems that everything works fine without specifying the `input_shape` in the first layer when building a `Sequential` model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

X_train = np.random.randn(1000, 10)
y_train = np.random.randn(1000)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1),
])
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.01, 0.9)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

This makes sense to me because Keras can easily get the input shape from the inputs (`X_train`). I also tried using PyPI Keras, and it works fine too (with the TensorFlow 1.9.0 backend).

So I have two questions:

1. why does the official Keras API [require](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#specifying-the-input-shape) the input shape to be specified in the first layer? Is it because it is necessary for backends other than TensorFlow?
2. is this behavior officially supported by `tf.keras`, even though it is not officially supported by the Keras API? In other words, if I do not care about other backends, is it legal to do this (not specify the input shape), or is there a risk it will break in future versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think the choice of words in the guide (emphasis mine),

> The model **needs** to know what input shape it should expect.

may be a bit unfortunate and, being a guide, should not been taken as a specification.

Keras can accept `input_shape`s that are partially `(None, n)` or completely `(None, None)` unknown. The later is actually needed to create FCN networks that scale with the size of the input.

So it you know that you don't know the input shape, I would suggest to explicitly provide such a partially/completely undefined `input_shape`. It makes for self-documenting code claiming that the input shape is unknown, rather than casting some doubt on whether this argument is missing.

Comment: Why is the input_shape often written as (number,) with that comma and nothing after it?