# Keras Sequential without providing input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I currently have a keras model that looks like this:

```py
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(len(labels), activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

The [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#specifying-the-input-shape) tells me:

> The model needs to know what input shape it should expect. For this reason, the first layer in a Sequential model (and only the first, because following layers can do automatic shape inference) needs to receive information about its input shape

**However**, the model as it is actually trains fine, without errors, even though I never specified the shape of the inputs.

How does it know what shape to expect? What is the default behaviour if I don't provide an input shape? How will it affect my model?

*edit: this is using `tf.keras`, aka the Tensorflow backend for keras*

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355729/why-does-the-keras-api-require-the-input-shape-in-the-first-layer-since-it-actu

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nice observation - I believe the Keras documentation should be updated. When the input shape is not provided, Keras infers it from the argument `x` of `Model.fit` and only then it builds the whole model. Concretely, this is what's happening:

1. When adding Keras layers in the `Sequential` model, since the argument `input_shape` (and, by extension, `batch_input_shape`) is never set, the attribute `Model.inputs` remains `None` (see [`Sequential.add`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/sequential.py#L135-L180)).
2. Then, in `Model.fit`, they check whether `Model.inputs` has been set (see [`Model.fit`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1150) and [`Model._standardize_user_data`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/88ca804d94a0f978d0522d82a2e2bda26362076a/keras/engine/training.py#L500-L504)) and, when it hasn't, they infer the input shape from the provided input array.
3. Finally, in `Model._set_inputs`, they build the whole model with the inferred `input_shape` (see [`Model._set_inputs`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/88ca804d94a0f978d0522d82a2e2bda26362076a/keras/engine/training.py#L409-L417)).

---

This can be verified by printing some weights (e.g. `print(model.layers[0].get_weights())`) before fitting the model. You will see that, when the argument `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` is not provided to the first layer of the model, the weight's array is empty as the model is yet to be built.

Comment: This seems to be the most correct answer. Shape detection isn't a tensorflow-specific feature, but it's only documented properly in `tf.keras`.

Answer (score 2):

The document [The Sequential model](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/#specifying-the-input-shape-in-advance) has been updated in 2020/04/12. The section [Specifying the input shape in advance](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/#specifying-the-input-shape-in-advance) clarifies this problem.

> When you instantiate a Sequential model without an input shape, it isn't "built": it has no weights (and calling `model.weights` results in an error stating just this). The weights are created when the model **first** sees some input data:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


model1 = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(2, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(4),
    ]
)  # No weights at this stage!

for layer in model1.layers:
    print(layer.weights)  # Empty

# At this point, you can't do this:
# model1.weights

# You also can't do this:
# model1.summary()

# Call the model on a test input
x = tf.ones((1, 4))
y = model1(x)

# Once a model is "built", you can call its summary() method to display its contents:

model1.summary()
```

> You could start your model by passing an [`Input`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) object to your model, so that it knows its input shape from the start:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model2 = keras.Sequential()
model2.add(keras.Input(shape=(4,)))
model2.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="relu"))
model2.add(layers.Dense(3, activation="relu"))
model2.add(layers.Dense(4))

for layer in model2.layers:
    print(layer.weights)

print(model2.weights)

model2.summary()
```

> A simple alternative is to just pass an `input_shape` argument to your first layer:

```py
model2.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", input_shape=(4,)))
```

> Models built with a predefined input shape like this always have weights (even before seeing any data) and always have a defined output shape.

At last, the document says:

> In general, it's a recommended best practice to always specify the input shape of a Sequential model in advance if you know what it is.

Back to your question:

> How does it know what shape to expect?

If no input shape is defined, the model will match the data it first sees.

```py
x = tf.ones((1, 4))
y = model1(x)

model1.summary()

# Output
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_2 (Dense)              (1, 2)                    10        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (1, 3)                    9         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (1, 4)                    16        
=================================================================
Total params: 35
Trainable params: 35
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

```py
x = tf.ones((3, 5, 10))
y = model1(x)
model1.summary()

# Output:
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_2 (Dense)              (3, 5, 2)                 22        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (3, 5, 3)                 9         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (3, 5, 4)                 16        
=================================================================
Total params: 47
Trainable params: 47
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

> What is the default behavior if I don't provide an input shape? How will it affect my model?

If you don't specify the input shape of model in advance, the model has no weights and you can't call `model.summary()` since it isn't built.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a miscorrelation between the TensorFlow version and the Keras documentation.

As far as I can see, the documentation that you are referring to is the one from Keras, while the TensorFlow version that you use is 2.0.0 >= alpha version, whose Keras internal version is different.

You should check the Keras documentation within TensorFlow 2.0, otherwise you might very well run into mismatches.

Comment: You seem to be right. On [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) of the TF documentation (not Keras) it says "Note that you can also omit the `input_shape` argument: In that case the model gets built the first time you call `fit` (or other training and evaluation methods)."

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it would be better to have a look there. Keras from TF 2.0 contains a couple of differences as compared to 'barebones' Keras.

Comment: I tested it for the plain keras - the behavior is the same